# Cannot center on the marker in Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have this code below to generate a Google Map, but the map doesn't center at the marker. I've done some research but can't figure it out.

The JavaScript code I use:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { position: latitude + ',' + longitude, center: latitude + ',' + longitude, zoom: 10, draggable:false });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
var c = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude , longitude);
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { position: c , zoom: 10, draggable:false });
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': c});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude , longitude);
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { position: LatLng , center: LatLng, zoom: 10 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but seems like it doesn't center the map any way. The code above says that it should work. But I'm creating google maps dynamically, could that be an issue you think?